# How to route "pretty" dynamic URL (without query string) in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Well, i know the title isn't very specific, but i couldn't find a better succint description of what i'm looking for.

i want to have a default.aspx so that when a user types:
http://www.mydomain.com/randomstring
i can use the randomstring to query a table on page load.

More specific:
. I will be importing batches of users to my database through a csv file.
. in that process, a random string will be generated
. i will send that url to each user by email
. when the user clicks through that link, i want my aspx(c#) to interpret that string, query a table that gives me a second url, this one with querystring, and Redirects the user to that second address

I'm just looking for the interpretation part of the problem. I know how unsafe the whole process is, and i don't care for now, it's not critic at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET routing engine (introduced in .NET 3.5 SP1), see this article for quick-start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

Comment: thanx, i will check it out. I will mark this as the right answer as soon as i have time to read the docs

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry but i got deviated to another project,, i didn't have time to check this out. I managed to give it a quick glance and i think this is exactly what i'm looking for so i'm going to mark this as the right answer. thanx